# How to add image watermarker on video in iOS Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avplayer

I have bee trying to add image overlay on video and save video to device library with video overlay.

```
let myURL = "https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4"

let url = URL(string:myURL)

player = AVPlayer(url: url!)

avpController.player = player
avpController.player?.play()
avpController.showsPlaybackControls = false


avpController.view.frame.size.height = videoView.frame.size.height

avpController.view.frame.size.width = videoView.frame.size.width

self.videoView.addSubview(avpController.view)
```

How to add image overlay on video? any help much appreciated pls..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created this

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        shareClicked()
    }

     func shareClicked() {

        let url = URL(string:"https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4")!

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

            if let urlData = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {


                let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!

                let fileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsPath).appendingPathComponent("fffffff.mp4")

                if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath:fileUrl.path) {

                    try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at:fileUrl)

                    print("removed")
                }

                try? urlData.write(to: fileUrl)


                self.merge(video: fileUrl.path, withForegroundImage:UIImage(named: "images.png")!, completion: { (uuu) in

                            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                                self.play(uuu!)
                            }

                        })


                }

        }

    }
    func play(_ url : URL) {

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            let vc = AVPlayerViewController()

            vc.player = AVPlayer(url: url)

            vc.player?.externalPlaybackVideoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspect

            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }

    }
    private func addAudioTrack(composition: AVMutableComposition, videoUrl: URL) {


        let videoUrlAsset = AVURLAsset(url: videoUrl, options: nil)

        let audioTracks = videoUrlAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio)

        let compositionAudioTrack:AVMutableCompositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID())!

        for audioTrack in audioTracks {
            try! compositionAudioTrack.insertTimeRange(audioTrack.timeRange, of: audioTrack, at: CMTime.zero)
        }
    }


    func merge(
        video videoPath: String,
        withForegroundImage foregroundImage: UIImage,
        completion: @escaping (URL?) -> Void) -> () {

        let videoUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: videoPath)
        let videoUrlAsset = AVURLAsset(url: videoUrl, options: nil)

        // Setup `mutableComposition` from the existing video
        let mutableComposition = AVMutableComposition()
        let videoAssetTrack = videoUrlAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video).first!
        let videoCompositionTrack = mutableComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
        videoCompositionTrack?.preferredTransform = videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform
        try! videoCompositionTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRange(start:CMTime.zero, duration:videoAssetTrack.timeRange.duration), of: videoAssetTrack, at: CMTime.zero)

        addAudioTrack(composition: mutableComposition, videoUrl: videoUrl)

        let videoSize: CGSize = (videoCompositionTrack?.naturalSize)!
        let frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: videoSize.width, height: videoSize.height)
        let imageLayer = CALayer()
        imageLayer.contents = foregroundImage.cgImage
        imageLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width:50, height:50)


        let videoLayer = CALayer()
        videoLayer.frame = frame
        let animationLayer = CALayer()
        animationLayer.frame = frame
        animationLayer.addSublayer(videoLayer)
        animationLayer.addSublayer(imageLayer)

        let videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition(propertiesOf: (videoCompositionTrack?.asset!)!)
        videoComposition.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videoLayer, in: animationLayer)

        let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.cachesDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true).first!
        let documentDirectoryUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectory)
        let destinationFilePath = documentDirectoryUrl.appendingPathComponent("result.mp4")

        do {

            if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: destinationFilePath.path) {

                try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: destinationFilePath)

                print("removed")
            }



        } catch {

            print(error)
        }


        let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession( asset: mutableComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)!

       exportSession.videoComposition = videoComposition
        exportSession.outputURL = destinationFilePath
        exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileType.mp4
        exportSession.exportAsynchronously { [weak exportSession] in
            if let strongExportSession = exportSession {
                completion(strongExportSession.outputURL!)

                //self.play(strongExportSession.outputURL!)
            }
        }

    }

}
```

And you will get this result

[image]

Comment: How to set water marker at top-left corner, i tried to change frame x, y position but its coming correctly..

Comment: it's not working on my side. can you please eleborate so i can check it.

Comment: @PvDev It looks like y starts from the bottom. So if you want your watermark on the top left, you should set y to 'videoSize.height'

Comment: This answer works great, however if the video or animation is long then the user has to wait while until the video has finished exporting. There is a way to do this with `AVSynchronizedLayer` that makes the animations render as the video is playing.

Comment: audio is not working in this code

Answer (score 0):

[Shehata Gamal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5820010/shehata-gamal) is right but I think there needs to be update.
This code worked but when i added a video from library and added a filter to it then added an overlay then it failed to export video . I found the solution

```
let videoCompositionTrack = mutableComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
```

Replaced with:

```
let videoCompositionTrack = mutableComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video, preferredTrackID: videoAssetTrack.trackID)
```